# Former employee's email access by former employer

Tags: communication

How do I find out if my former employer is sending emails to clients using my past work email address pretending to be me?

Comment: Why do you think this could be the case?

Comment: Where are you located? I don't think there is a way. Have you updated your linkedin?

Comment: Your former work email address belongs to your former employer. They can do whatever they want with it. If you think they're doing something illegal and using your former work email address in this illegal activity then you should contact an attorney. Otherwise, you should drop it.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find out if my former employer is sending emails to clients
> using my past work email address pretending to be me?

Talk to the clients. Or ask your former coworkers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find if anyone is using your former e-mail address, without help from the inside.

However, you can make a small test: see if your e-mail address is still active. Just send a short e-mail to that address. If you do not get an error telling you that the e-mail address does not exist, then your e-mail address mightstill exists, and might still be active and can be abused. You can have a real, clear answer only if you get in contact with the company.

You might want to send that test e-mail from an e-mail address which cannot be traced back to you. But that is part of your strategy on how to deal with the problem.

---

Note: even though the e-mail address itself belongs to the company, your identity belongs to you, and no-one should use your e-mail address.

Another note: "generic" e-mail addresses are there to be used by the company as they see fit, anyone being potentially allowed to use them. Example: sales@company.com, support@company.org ...

Comment: "your identity belongs to you, and no-one should use your e-mail address." I am not so sure about that, why would it be wrong for company to monitor ex-employee inbox and then reply from it that the employee is no longer with them and they should contact X instead? Pretending to be OP, sure, wrong, but using ex-employee inbox I don't think that there is anything wrong with that.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul My understanding is that can vary a bit with jurisdiction. In the US, it would [appear to be the case that the employer can keep using the e-mail address](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/career-management/what-are-ex-employees-legal-rights-in-regard-to-old-email-address/) whereas in places like Germany there tend to be more restrictions on this sort of thing. The blanket statement in this answer is almost certainly wrong though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: what do you mean by "blanket statement"?

Comment: @virolino you've pinged the wrong person. But I think what Philip means is that what you said, without any qualifier for region, specific use, is not accurate, as we know for a fact that it's allowed for companies to use ex-employee email in places like USA.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: sorry for the wrong ping, I changed it :) Tnx for letting me know

Comment: @PhilipKendall: "mining the incoming traffic" for business-related communications is one thing. Creating traffic (impersonating) is another (`"There would potentially be an issue if the employer used the former employee's e-mail to perpetuate a false impression that the employee remained with the company"`). I just quoted from the link you provided. So even in the US, things are not so simple, as it seems (I am not an expert in US matters whatsoever).

Comment: @virolino your test might not work. Many email systems are configured to not respond to an external message if the  address doesn't match an active account.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: you are right, I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the USA? If the email is theirs to begin with, then they have an absolute right to use it to conduct business. If you choose to tell your former clients otherwise, there's a good chance your employer may take you to court and they would win, especially if you signed non-compete clauses and you tell the client that you're working elsewhere and to contact you there.

On the issue of personal business, such as banking or whatnot that you send to your previous work email. Many have features to switch out emails but in the respect of them accessing your account, that is possible. I do notice sometimes companies would take previous employee emails, then have it forward to a group email. So it is possible your banking info or other personal emails are seen by others.

My recommendation is to go into these accounts that you know is being sent to your previous work, and change them. Also change out any password or otherwise from these accounts to safe guard them and enable 2-factor authentication if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone!